# Using Tomcat Basic Auth with new WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

OK so I've previously used this technique with classic web.xml, but am having trouble getting it to work now that I'm using the WebApplicationInitializer.

My WebApplicationInitializer includes this code:

```
HttpConstraintElement constraint = new HttpConstraintElement(
        TransportGuarantee.NONE,
        new String[]{"sponsorUsers"});
ServletSecurityElement servletSecurity =
        new ServletSecurityElement(constraint);
dispatcher.setServletSecurity(servletSecurity);
```

I'm trying to require basic auth (username+password) for any http methods for any resource request within the servlet.
All I get back is a 403 - no prompt for the username.
My suspicion is that I need to set the auth-method to BASIC, as I would in xml:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>User Auth</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

But don't see the equivalent in the Java classes.  Any help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `WebApplicationInitializer` is basically the Spring extension of Servlet 3.0 `ServletContainerInitializer`.

There are a few things you cannot do with `ServletContainerInitializer`, or `ServletContext` to be more specific, and one of them is to configure some security components, ex `login-config`.

Instead you can have both a `ServletContainerInitializer` and a `web.xml` using the attribute `metadata-complete` set to `false`. For example,

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false" version="3.0">
```

In which you then add your `<login-config>` element.

Comment: @Bobby You're welcome. Keep an eye out for updates. The above might no longer be true in future versions.