# Spring Boot with container security

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I've been using spring boot for some projects lately and I really like it.  For a new project, we'd like to use tomcat-users.xml for really basic authentication, but I can't figure out how to use the  mechanism without a web.xml file.  Most people using spring boot seem to be using spring security.

Is it possible to use tomcat container security with the spring boot java config model?  I understand this breaks the runnable jar paradigm but we're planning to deploy this as a war anyway.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25999919/28214 where there is an example of configuring users programmatically.

Comment: That's great information on setting up the users programatically, but it doesn't cover how to protect a url resource with container security, which is the piece I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Spring Security Project, I'd recommend using Spring Security as it does more than container Security (i.e. protection against common exploits, method security to provide defense in depth, etc). However, if you want to use container security you can as shown below:

You can use the following to use container managed security a Spring Boot 2.7.x or 3.0.0 Application:

Create a file at `src/main/resources/tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="ROLE_USER"/>
    <user username="user" password="password" roles="ROLE_USER"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Create the following Spring Configuration:

```
package example;

import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator;
import org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm;
import org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.LoginConfig;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityCollection;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint;

import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * @author Rob Winch
 */
@Configuration
public class ContainerSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                context.getPipeline().addValve(new BasicAuthenticator());
                context.setRealm(createRealm());
                context.setLoginConfig(createLoginConfig());
                context.addSecurityRole("ROLE_USER");
                context.addConstraint(createSecurityConstraint());
            }

            private static RealmBase createRealm() {
                MemoryRealm memoryRealm = new MemoryRealm();
                memoryRealm.setPathname(getTomcatUsersPath());
                return memoryRealm;
            }

            // this must find the path to tomcat-users.xml, here we find 
            // it as a resource, but you can provide an absolute path to 
            // any place on your file system
            private static String getTomcatUsersPath() {
                String resourceName = "/tomcat-users.xml";
                URL resource = ContainerSecurityConfiguration.class.getResource(resourceName);
                if (resource == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find resource " + resourceName);
                }
                return resource.getPath();
            }

            private static LoginConfig createLoginConfig() {
                LoginConfig config = new LoginConfig();
                config.setRealmName("basic");
                config.setAuthMethod("BASIC");
                return config;
            }

            // /private/* -> ROLE_USER
            private static SecurityConstraint createSecurityConstraint() {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setDisplayName("Private resources");
                SecurityCollection securityCollection = new SecurityCollection();
                securityCollection.addPattern("/private/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(securityCollection);
                securityConstraint.addAuthRole("ROLE_USER");
                return securityConstraint;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Here is an automated test you can use:

```
package example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate rest;

    @Test
    public void authenticationRequired() {
        ResponseEntity<String> result = this.rest.getForEntity("/private", String.class);
        assertThat(result.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    @Test
    public void authorizationSuccess() {
        ResponseEntity<String> result = this.rest.withBasicAuth("user", "password").getForEntity("/private", String.class);
        assertThat(result.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
        assertThat(result.getBody()).isEqualTo("private message");
    }

}
```

## No XML

If you do not want to use the xml file you can also manage your users pragmatically. First create a Tomcat Realm with the following:

```
package example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.catalina.realm.GenericPrincipal;
import org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase;
/**
 * @author Rob Winch
 */
class ProgramaticMemoryRealm extends RealmBase {
    private final Map<String, UserInformation> usernameToPrincipal = new HashMap<>();

    public ProgramaticMemoryRealm(UserInformation... users) {
        this(List.of(users));
    }

    public ProgramaticMemoryRealm(List<UserInformation> users) {
        users.stream().forEach(this::addUser);
    }

    private void addUser(UserInformation user) {
        this.usernameToPrincipal.put(user.user().getName(), user);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getPassword(String username) {
        UserInformation userInformation = this.usernameToPrincipal.get(username);
        return userInformation == null ? null : userInformation.password();
    }

    @Override
    protected GenericPrincipal getPrincipal(String username) {
        UserInformation userInformation = this.usernameToPrincipal.get(username);
        return userInformation == null ? null : userInformation.user();
    }

    public record UserInformation(GenericPrincipal user, String password) {

    }
}
```

Now in `ContainerSecurityConfiguration` instead of using `MemoryRealm` use `ProgramaticMemoryRealm`:

```
private static RealmBase createRealm() {
    GenericPrincipal user = new GenericPrincipal("user", "password", List.of("ROLE_USER"));
    return new ProgramaticMemoryRealm(new UserInformation(user, "password"));
}
```

NOTE: We use UserInformation because in Spring Boot 3+ the GenericPrincipal password is not accessible and the constructor with the password is deprecated. In Spring Boot 2.7 UserInformation is not really necessary since the password is fully available on GenericPrincipal.

Comment: Wow an eight year old question answered by Rob himself. Thanks for your dedication

Answer (score 8):

From [official Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html):

> WEB-INF/web.xml and WebApplicationInitializer use are not mutually exclusive; for example, web.xml can register one servlet, and a WebApplicationInitializer can register another. An initializer can even modify registrations performed in web.xml through methods such as ServletContext.getServletRegistration(String). However, if WEB-INF/web.xml is present in the application, its version attribute must be set to "3.0" or greater, otherwise ServletContainerInitializer bootstrapping will be ignored by the servlet container.

So, I solved with both `WebApplicationInitializer` (`SpringBootServletInitializer` extends `WebApplicationInitializer`) and `web.xml`.

Spring Boot Java Config Class:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

     @Override
     protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
         return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
     }

      //...
 }
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
metadata-complete="false" version="3.0">

    <display-name>My Awesome Application</display-name>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>My Awesome Resource Name</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>myawesomerole</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>

</web-app>
```

See also: [Using Tomcat Basic Auth with new WebApplicationInitializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875356/using-tomcat-basic-auth-with-new-webapplicationinitializer)